# Why do I need to assign this dereferenced iterator to a temporary value?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, nodes, dereference

I'm working on a project that contains a tree data-structure, with each Node in the tree storing pointers to child Nodes in a vector. In one of my functions, I'm trying to loop through the vector using iterators, but to get it to work, I have to assign the dereferenced iterator to a temporary variable as such:

```
std::vector<Node*>::iterator p;
for (p = n->children.begin(); p < n->children.end(); p++)
{
    Node* t = *p;
    // if board is complete, mark as such and update score
    if (t->m_board.isComplete())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If I try to write this same code without the temporary value: `if (*p->m_board.isComplete())` then I get the error message "expression must have pointer-to-class type. Is this not the case? Shouldn't dereferencing my iterator return a pointer to my Node class?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `operator->` has higher precedence than `operator*`, then `*p->m_board.isComplete()` is equivalent as `*(p->m_board.isComplete())`, compiler complains that `p->m_board.isComplete()` is ill-formed.

You could

```
if ((*p)->m_board.isComplete())
```

Answer (score 0):

Why `if (*p->m_board.isComplete())` fails is because in C++, the member access operator `->` has a [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the unary (or so called dereference) `*` operator. For such case, use braces to state your precedence: `if ((*p)->m_board.isComplete()) { ... }`

<strike>`std::vector`'s iterator has an overloaded `->` that can be used directly</strike>

```
std::vector<Node*>::iterator p;
for (p = n->children.begin(); p < n->children.end(); p++)
{
    // Node* t = *p; ....No need
    if (p->m_board.isComplete())  //This should work
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it can't be used "directly". Did you try it? http://rextester.com/ZCZWLA76469

Comment: The point is that iterator is pointing to a pointer here, so you have to use `operator*` to dereference on it and then use `operator->`. You can image the iterator works like `Node**` here. BTW: I'm not the downvoter. :)

Comment: @songyuanyao, Oh, I get it, my oversight... :-). Thanks.